# Pandas - Create Column Name Based on the values in a Column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create the column names based on the values in a column

This is what I have:

```
part_number source  recent_date  recent_price
    0023496     a1  2017-06-27    55.0
    0023496     e1  2017-08-03    315.0
    0023084     a1  2017-01-12    255.0
    0023084     e1    NaN           NaN
```

This is the output that I want:

```
part_number a1_recent_date   a1_recent_price   e1_recent_date e1_recent_price

0023496     2017-06-27       55.0               2017-08-03        315.0
0023084     2017-01-12      255.0                  NaN             NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `set_index` and `unstack`

```
In [520]: dff = df.set_index(['part_number', 'source']).unstack()

In [521]: dff
Out[521]:
            recent_date             recent_price
source               a1          e1           a1     e1
part_number
23084        2017-01-12         NaN        255.0    NaN
23496        2017-06-27  2017-08-03         55.0  315.0
```

Then, set the column names

```
In [522]: dff.columns = dff.columns.map(lambda x: '{1}_{0}'.format(*x))

In [523]: dff
Out[523]:
            a1_recent_date e1_recent_date  a1_recent_price  e1_recent_price
part_number
23084           2017-01-12            NaN            255.0              NaN
23496           2017-06-27     2017-08-03             55.0            315.0
```

---

Details

```
In [527]: df
Out[527]:
   part_number source recent_date  recent_price
0        23496     a1  2017-06-27          55.0
1        23496     e1  2017-08-03         315.0
2        23084     a1  2017-01-12         255.0
3        23084     e1         NaN           NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

This can do it:

```
pd.concat([agg_df.add_prefix(index+'_').reset_index() 
           for index,agg_df  in df.groupby('source', as_index=False)],
           axis=1)
```

#### Explanation:

1. create groups of dataframe based on the value of soure: `df.groupby('source', as_index=False)`
2. iterate through these group `for index,agg_df ...`
3. for each group add the source value as prefix and reset_index : `agg_df.add_prefix(index+'_').reset_index()`
4. Finally, concatenate all groups back to one dataframe: `pd.concat([...])`

---

Results:

```
In [46]: pd.concat([agg_df.add_prefix(index+'_').reset_index() 
    ...:            for index,agg_df  in df.groupby('source', as_index=False)],
    ...:            axis=1)  
Out[46]: 
   index a1_part_number a1_source a1_recent_date a1_recent_price  index  \
0      0        0023496        a1     2017-06-27            55.0      1   
1      2        0023084        a1     2017-01-12           255.0      3   

  e1_part_number e1_source e1_recent_date e1_recent_price  
0        0023496        e1     2017-08-03           315.0  
1        0023084        e1            NaN             NaN  

In [47]:
```